# Securing Memory Card?

Tags: security, external-sd

What should I do so that the Memory card in my phone works only in my phone? Also, I should be able to connect my mobile to a PC through a USB cable and completely see/edit/organize the data on my memory card.

I want this to prevent anyone from gaining physical asses to my mobile, removing the memory card and getting asses to my sensitive data, by using the memory card with some other device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that what you want to do is not possible.

You can come *close* by using EDS on the phone, but your computer will not be able to read the files directly. TrueCrypt will be able to decrypt the containers, but I think you might have some problems with handsets using MTP rather than USB Mass Storage.

Essentially what you want is for Android to support the "Secure" part of "Secure Digital". What you want to do is built into the SD card spec, where a password can be set on the card and can then only be read on that device.

For instance, the Samsung Focus WP7 handset locked SD cards to it, and these were not readable in other devices. Most devices simply saw the cards as unreadable, not even able to format them. Only Symbian handsets seemed to be able to recognise these cards were locked to a handset and were able to format these cards, but not read the data that was on them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use encryption on the entire drive. This can be done with certain apps like [EDS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sovworks.edslite) (which creates an encrypted container on the device, which requires a password to be opened -- but after that the file system is mounted transparently for all apps to access; these containers are [TrueCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truecrypt) compatible). Some of these Apps (like e.g. [Cryptonite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=csh.cryptonite) or [LUKS Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nemesis2.luksmanager)) require the device to be rooted.

However, if those encryption does not work on the device filesystem itself (but uses containers), I'm not sure how an app will work with it if it expects files at hard-coded places. You can try and find out, as most of the encryption apps offer free trial versions.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, to best of my knowledge it cannot be done.  But however, you can only encrypt your content. Please see this [post](http://lifehacker.com/5802279/is-the-data-on-my-androids-memory-card-safe-if-its-lost-or-stolen), which explains few alternate ways with which you can encrypt the files that are being stored.  [MobiSafeFile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trustmobi.mobisafefile) is one such application that helps you to encrypt.

Comment: Answer with only a link isn't considered a good answer. If the link dies this answer becomes useless. Also the users has to go to different site without knowing if he will get what he wants there. A little summary might be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use encryption on the entire drive. This can be done with certain apps like EDS (which creates an encrypted container on the device, which requires a password to be opened -- but after that the file system is mounted transparently for all apps to access; these containers are TrueCrypt compatible). Some of these Apps (like e.g. Cryptonite or LUKS Manager) require the device to be rooted.